# What is the name of the jailbreak tweak that allowed non-Max iPhones to lock landscape orientation (and not just vertical) from the Control Center?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweaks

I went through an unintended restore of an **iPhone** and lost a **jailbreak tweak** I know exist.

What it did was basically enhancing the original functions of the “Portrait Orientation Lock” control center button **for iPhones**, and added the function to also lock in landscape. **(This is something iPads are supposed to be able to do, but iPhones normally aren’t.)**

Very simple jailbreak tweak, and worked better than any other predictive work around sto achieve the same.

It worked on iOS 14.3,  but may have been developed earlier, and never officially tested for this version of iOS. Therefore, any tweaks that do this marked for earlier versions of the OS would be welcome.

This feature is available on all iPads, and many, if not all, Max-size iPhones (for e.g., iPhone X(S) Max, iPhone 13 Pro Max etc.); however, it has been OEM blocked from iOS to support non-Max-size iPhones.

Comment: It’s called [Orientation Lock](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/change-or-lock-the-screen-orientation-ipad997da805/ipados).  Funny thing is, I just checked my devices (Control Center Settings) and that control is gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the (better!) tweaks that do this I found is [NoForcePortraitLock](https://www.ios-repo-updates.com/repository/dgh0st-s-repo/package/com.dgh0st.noforceportraitlock/) which, unlike a greatly similar tweak, also allows the orientation to lock on landscape with the notch on the left and not just the right. (A similar tweak interferes with the control center in a way that you can’t pull it down oriented with the notch to the left instead of the right)

This tweak is also compatible with FloatingDockPlus 13/14, Gyration and [Pivot](https://github.com/kritanta-ios-tweaks/Pivot/raw/master/packages/me.kritanta.pivot_0.2.2_iphoneos-arm.deb) (the official repo is not, but the tweak is still available—under the link on GitHub), and I can confirm that it runs from iOS 5 up to iOS 14.3 instead of the official compatibility only confirming iOS 13.x.x.

Answer (score 2):

This is strange, it used to be in Control center but is no longer (iOS 16.3.1) on my iPhone.

I did find a page that showed you how to turn that on and off but it is under Accessibility and requires you to use the back tap feature:

Settings > Accessibility > Physical and Motor > Touch > Back Tap > [select] Double Tap or Triple Tap > Lock Rotation

Found it on [MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/change-iphone-rotation-lock-no-control-center/)

Comment: The question relates to iPhones where it only was possible with jailbreak tweaks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, *I used to have orientation lock in my control center* and I have never jailbroken my phone. Also a number of tutorials I found show it as available easily as an option for control center. So no jailbreak required.

Comment: I have very serious doubts about the accuracy of that claim. Maybe if you used the accessibility features or potentially on the Max size iPhones. The mini, SE, Pro and numbered-only series, to my knowledge, did not have this ability. On these phones, it was not call orientation lock, but “Portrait Orientation Lock”. It did, indeed, exist on many if not all iPad’s, however.

Comment: Could the confusion come from the fact that the rotation lock in Control Center only locks portrait mode (and has done so for ages) while the OP wants to lock landscape mode?

Comment: @nohillside Indeed. And probably from the fact that the tutorials on Apple's site has been clearly made in error—unless for any reason intentionally misleading.